# Gets the list of parameters serialized to json

Tags: c#-4.0, json

I have a C# method called

```
Void getCompanyAddresses(int iCompanyId, int iPersonId, string PersonName)
```

What i want to create is JSON data for current methods parameters and its values, for above example JSON object is like

```
{"iCompanyId":1214,"iPersonId":51,"PersonName":"Chetan"}
```

I also need to check the total size of parameters & its values are not greater than 1 MB.

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Chets,try this http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: try another one http://forums.asp.net/t/1685080.aspx/1